# Flash Builder 4.6 bugs

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm developing an actionscript3 project in FB and I've faced the following bug. Once I write a code, which runs into some error e. g. `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` I can not delete this code! I mean, I do delete it, but the compiler says there is an error on line, *which doesn't exist any more*.

Is it only me? How do I fix this bug?

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class AirHockey extends MovieClip
    {

        public function AirHockey():void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Compiler says there's an error on line 200, but I've deleted the whole code and there's no **line 200**

Comment: @bitmapdata.com, I delete the whole code, there's no code: just empty class, and the compiler says there's an error on line 200 for example,  but there are only 10 lines in a file now. Compiler remembers the state of file and doesn't apply changes.

Comment: you try this process
`Flash Builder - Project - Clean`

Comment: Didn't work for me... Moved the whole project to Flash Develop and it ran perfectly... Thanks for help anyways

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer? :)

Comment: @RytisAlekna In fact the only thing I did **NOT** try is to dance around my PC with a shaman tambourine. Since it was just a trial version, I just deleted this piece of sh^w program code and installed free open souce Flash Develop, which works well.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the project or workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfixable bug... Installed opensource `Flash Develop`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a few times with 4.6.  The only solution I've found was to delete the entire class file (from the disk) and create a new one.  Never found out why that works, but it does.